# Raspberry Pi Desktop always launches into the first install wizard

Tags: boot, raspberry-pi-desktop

I am installing Raspberry Pi Desktop onto a VM in Parallels.  Everytime it boots up (I do select "Run with Persistance" at the start) it launches the first-time boot wizard ("Before you start using it, there are a few things to set up."). I select the options, it runs a while and seems to succeed except it will always have one error `Error while installing packages - unable to make backup link of "some file.svg" before installing the new version`.  The file it can't back varies I think, this last time it was `./user/share/icons/gnome/scalable/apps/libreoffice-math.svg`.  Anyhow after it completes and the machine restarts (and I again select "Run with Persistance in the bios startup menu) it repeats the whole process again.

Any idea how to have it finish and not run the first-boot experience again?

Answer (score 1):

I have seen messages like *unable to make backup link of "some file.svg"* when trying to install software on a **fat** formated partition. **fat** does not support links so this message will come up every time something tries to set a link. May it be possible that you try to use a **fat** partition in any way? I have never used [Raspberry Pi Desktop](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspberry-pi-desktop/) but as written there it is based on *Debian Stretch* and that cannot run on a **fat** partition. It needs an **ext4** formated partition.

Comment: [*They*](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspberry-pi-desktop/) call it that.

Comment: @Ghanima Ah.. that's it. I will correct the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the problem I had was the bootup option I choose.  The correct option would have been to choose "Graphical Installer" (there are two install options, probably either, but I went with the graphical one).

The "Run with Persistance" option was just running the OS from the CD.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got this to work -- many tries Installed VM with hyper-v using tutorial on https://www.avoiderrors.com/how-to-install-raspbian-os-on-hyper-v/

when the RPi image boots it will loop in the install unless you select skip updates. If you don't, you will get another chance soon

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).